# Preserve HTML font-size when iPhone orientation changes from portrait to landscape

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have a mobile web application with an unordered list containing multiple items with a hyperlink inside each `li`:

My question is: how can I format the hyperlinks so that they DON'T change size when viewed on an iPhone, and the accelerometer switches from portrait to landscape?

In portrait mode, I have the hyperlink font size set at `14px`, but when I switch the device to landscape, it blows way up to `20px`.

I would like the font-size to stay the same.

Here is the example code:

```css
ul li a {
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #cc9999;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="home" class="active">
      <a href="home.html">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li id="home" class="active">
      <a href="test.html">TEST</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 484, accepted):

You can disable this behavior through the `-webkit-text-size-adjust` CSS property:

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Prevent font scaling in landscape while allowing user zoom */
}
```

The use of this property is described further in the [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006510-SW16).

Comment: As snobojohan notes you can wrap this in a landscape-specific media query to preserve the ability to increase the font size on desktop browsers. This is not necessary on iOS-targeted pages where pinch zooming will work regardless.

Comment: This feature seams not to work in iOS6. You can also try using `<meta content="viewport"` meta tag (see below)

Comment: Still working for me on iOS 6. No need to disable zooming entirely.

Comment: @Dan it does work in iOS6 and it also works in iOS7.

Comment: DON'T use `none`, use `100%` instead, **that's** the behavior you want: http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/iphone-text-resizing/

Comment: Thank you for this... I have been trying to figure out what was going on with font-sizing in landscape xD

Comment: @bfred.it +1, I think it'd be worthwhile editing this answer with that change.

Comment: After looking for hours, finally the genius! Thanks!

Comment: It's an amazing tip.  Particularly useful if you have captive html locally on the device (to display typical long text "About" pages, etc).

Comment: Awesome! And it not only solves hyperlink font-size problems. I had trouble with rotated texts and font-sizes. Debug console shows correct rule but calculated value was different. This rule solved it! Huge thanks!

Comment: After hours of searching, I finally found this! Thank you!

Comment: We should also consider using moz and ms prefixes, as in `html { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;}` as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892327/why-is-font-size-changing-depending-on-portrait-or-landscape-for-mobile-devices/40892507#40892507

Comment: Almost a decade later, this answer is still preventing self-harm. Thank you!

Answer (score 115):

Note: if you use

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

then this will disable zoom behavior in default browsers. A better solution is:

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

This corrects the iPhone/iPad behavior, without changing desktop behavior.

Answer (score 27):

Using -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; directly on html breaks the ability to zoom text in all webkit browsers. You should combine this with som media queries specific for iOS. For example:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
     html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
     }
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough I only got it to work by putting the -webkit property inside the media query. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

As it was mentioned before, CSS rule

```
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none
```

does no longer work in modern devices.

Fortunately, a new solution comes for iOS5 and iOS6 *(todo: what about iOS7?)*:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

You can also add `, user-scalable=0` to turn off pinch zooming, so your website would behave like a native app. If your design brakes when user zooms, use this meta tag instead:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Comment: Well, a good question is whether to use comma or semicolon separator in this meta tag! But it works :)

Comment: I only need `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` for it to take effect.

Comment: @Foxinni: thanks, updated the answer. I think these 2 first meta tags were a deprecated garbage from early iOS versions

Answer (score 11):

You could also opt for using a CSS reset, such as [normalize.css](http://git.io/normalize), which includes the same rule that crazygringo recommends:

```
/**
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

As you see, it also includes a vendor specific rule for the IE Phone.

For current information about the implementation in different browsers, refer to [the MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust).

Answer (score 9):

You can add a meta in the HTML header:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />`

Answer (score 7):

As of March 2019 [text-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust) has [a reasonable support amongst mobile browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-size-adjusthttps://).

```
body {
  text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Using `viewport` meta tag has no effect on the text size adjustment and setting `user-scalable: no` [does not even work in IOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari).

Answer (score 3):

The below code works for me.

```
html{-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;}
```

Try with clearing your browser cache if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this trouble has been because I used CSS attribute `width: 100%` for HTML tag `input type="text"`.

I changed value of `width` to 60% and add `padding-right:38%`.

```
input {
    padding-right: 38%;
    width: 60%;
}
```