# Why does font-size CSS not work on iPad HTML emails?

Tags: css, ipad, html-email

I'm working on an HTML email and have been running to a problem on the mail client on the iPad only.

It seems that setting inline CSS to "font-size: 12px" or any other size does not work on the mail app for iPad, despite the font-size displaying correctly in the Mail app for Mac OS X.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Webkit automatically adjusts font-sizes on the ipad for easy reading. This CSS fixes the problem:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Comment: on which level? body or html?

Comment: I tried setting this property on a td and it worked fine. I also tried it on a span and it worked fine.

Comment: Excellent!!! I added this into the email body and it worked for all the font-size occurrencies in the code:
    <style>body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }</style>

Answer (score 3):

The WebKit layout engine automatically adjusts font-sizes.

As of this post, [Webkit is commonly used in Safari, Chrome, Kindle and Palm Browsers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based)

Applications can also take advantage of WebKit.

The problem comes down to [minimum 'font-size: 13px;'](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3339/save-your-layout-by-overriding-the-minimum-font-size-on-the-iphone-and/)

A CSS work-around:

`<style type="text/css">

div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }

</style>`

---

One issue is when creating e-Mail Signatures, for  tags may be over-written or stripped.
Please Note that inline WebKit Styling will be stripped out of Gmail's Web Client.

Answer (score 1):

**Does it support composing styled text? (i.e., bold, italics, font sizes)**
No (confirmed), aside from any formatting carried over by copy-and-paste from Safari or other apps. (It definitely supports displaying HTML/rich text messages.)

http://www.macintouch.com/reviews/ipad/faq.html

Comment: Just to clarify: this is in an html email, and I'm using lots of HTML and in-line CSS already that works.

Font-styles DO work on the mail app for iPad. Bolding works, even text-transform works, but notably font-size is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
<!--

/*
    I began with the goal to prevent font scaling in Landscape orientation.
    To do this, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710764/

    Later, I just wanted to magnify font-size for the iPad, leaving
    the iPhone rendering to the css code.  So ...

    (max-device-width:480px) = iphone.css
    (min-device-width:481px) and
        (max-device-width:1024px) and
            (orientation:portrait) = ipad-portrait.css
    (min-device-width:481px) and
        (max-device-width:1024px) and
            (orientation:landscape) = ipad-landscape.css
    (min-device-width:1025px) = ipad-landscape.css

*/

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
{
    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 140%;
    }
}

-->
</style>

</head>
```