# iPad layout scales up when rotating from portrait to landscape

Tags: html, ipad, meta-tags, viewport

I have a added to the `"viewport"` meta tag `"width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"` and on an iPad the page loads up fine in landscape mode, the it switches nicely to portrait and when I rotate it back to landscape it scales the page up and I have to pinch zoom it back to a 1 scale.

I can fix this by adding the `"maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"`, but I was wondering if there is a way I could fix this without taking away from the user the ability to zoom in the page.

If you have any suggestions I would love to hear them,
Thanks!

Comment: Does the 140% work, or the 100%?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

------ Update ------

This is not an issue anymore in iOS7. And there is better fix by Scott Jehl on github [scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix](https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix) that works for iOS6.

------ Original answer ------

Jeremy Keith ([@adactio](http://twitter.com/adactio)) has a good solution for this on  his blog [Orientation and scale](http://adactio.com/journal/4470/)

Keep the Markup scalable

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Then disable scalability with javascript until *gesturestart* with this script:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
    if (viewportmeta) {
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0';
        document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () {
            viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6';
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem like a real solution though — iPad is behaving badly, this is bad design on their side, I'd say.

Comment: This bug is fixed in iOS6. Check Jeremy Keith's latest post on this issue: [iOS Six Fix](http://adactio.com/journal/5802/). The below mentioned [fix by Scott Jehl](https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix) adapted the iOS bug fix.

Comment: @Ludder the iOS 6 fix should probably be a separate answer, comments are too easy to miss.

Comment: I am using the same viewport tag on iOS6. But still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I am also encountering this same issue under iOS 6.

Comment: Beware that `navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)` tests true in Android native browser.

Answer (score 12):

[Scott Jehl](http://scottjehl.com/) came up with a fantastic solution that uses the accelerometer to anticipate orientation changes.  This solution is very responsive and does not interfere with zoom gestures.

https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix

> How it works: This fix works by listening to the device's
>   accelerometer to predict when an orientation change is about to occur.
>   When it deems an orientation change imminent, the script disables user
>   zooming, allowing the orientation change to occur properly, with
>   zooming disabled. The script restores zoom again once the device is
>   either oriented close to upright, or after its orientation has
>   changed. This way, user zooming is never disabled while the page is in
>   use.

Minified source:

```
/*! A fix for the iOS orientationchange zoom bug. Script by @scottjehl, rebound by @wilto.MIT License.*/(function(m){if(!(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)&&navigator.userAgent.indexOf("AppleWebKit")>-1)){return}var l=m.document;if(!l.querySelector){return}var n=l.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]"),a=n&&n.getAttribute("content"),k=a+",maximum-scale=1",d=a+",maximum-scale=10",g=true,j,i,h,c;if(!n){return}function f(){n.setAttribute("content",d);g=true}function b(){n.setAttribute("content",k);g=false}function e(o){c=o.accelerationIncludingGravity;j=Math.abs(c.x);i=Math.abs(c.y);h=Math.abs(c.z);if(!m.orientation&&(j>7||((h>6&&i<8||h<8&&i>6)&&j>5))){if(g){b()}}else{if(!g){f()}}}m.addEventListener("orientationchange",f,false);m.addEventListener("devicemotion",e,false)})(this);
```

Comment: The idea here is good, but because this solution uses the accelerometer to predict orientation changes, it sometimes fails to detect a change if the iPad is held at an angle, i.e. it needs to be held almost perfectly upright for this to work.

Comment: This would be a far better solution if it detected this situation: 
1) user is in portrait with device relatively flat
2) rotates device without tilting
3) tilts device up to prompt the device to change orientation

Worded that way, it doesn't sound common, but this happens to me when I'm reading all the time.

Comment: FYI: `(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(navigator.platform)` is broken on Desktop Mode on iOS/iPadOS 13 (Mobile Safari 13) because it now gets set to MacIntel on iOS/iPadOS (Tested on Beta 2).

Answer (score 9):

Hopefully, this will help ...

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
<!--

/*
    I began with the goal to prevent font scaling in Landscape orientation.
    To do this, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710764/

    Later, I just wanted to magnify font-size for the iPad, leaving
    the iPhone rendering to the css code.  So ...

    (max-device-width:480px) = iphone.css
    (min-device-width:481px) and
        (max-device-width:1024px) and
            (orientation:portrait) = ipad-portrait.css
    (min-device-width:481px) and
        (max-device-width:1024px) and
            (orientation:landscape) = ipad-landscape.css
    (min-device-width:1025px) = ipad-landscape.css

*/

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)
{
    html {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 140%;   /* none for no scaling */
    }
}

-->
</style>

</head>
```

Comment: Hmm... So many proposed javascript solutions to find and it still jumps around (when you have absolutely positioned elements etc.) or disables zoom or something like that. And then I find this simple solution - in CSS! That makes smooth non-zooming rotation. This is just plain perfect and should be the correct answer to all questions of this issue! Thanks alot @John Love. This is absolutely amazing

Comment: With regards to the question you deleted John, when you downvote others it records that against you too.

Comment: After thinking about this for a while, I do recall reading a long time ago what I considered to be a rude comment from someone ... so I called him on it.  I really would appreciate some explanation on this issue.

Comment: Tried values none and 100%: This works on the first rotate, but on subsequent rotations I get strange results (on iOS6 Simulator)

Comment: Very nice--solved my problem with `font-size` changes specified in media queries not being rendered correctly in landscape mode on iPhone 5S.

Answer (score 3):

The fix used by jQuery mobile is here

https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix

Minified

```
/*! A fix for the iOS orientationchange zoom bug. Script by @scottjehl, rebound by @wilto.MIT / GPLv2 License.*/(function (a) { function m() { d.setAttribute("content", g), h = !0 } function n() { d.setAttribute("content", f), h = !1 } function o(b) { l = b.accelerationIncludingGravity, i = Math.abs(l.x), j = Math.abs(l.y), k = Math.abs(l.z), (!a.orientation || a.orientation === 180) && (i > 7 || (k > 6 && j < 8 || k < 8 && j > 6) && i > 5) ? h && n() : h || m() } var b = navigator.userAgent; if (!(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(navigator.platform) && /OS [1-5]_[0-9_]* like Mac OS X/i.test(b) && b.indexOf("AppleWebKit") > -1)) return; var c = a.document; if (!c.querySelector) return; var d = c.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]"), e = d && d.getAttribute("content"), f = e + ",maximum-scale=1", g = e + ",maximum-scale=10", h = !0, i, j, k, l; if (!d) return; a.addEventListener("orientationchange", m, !1), a.addEventListener("devicemotion", o, !1) })(this);
```

Full source

```
/*! A fix for the iOS orientationchange zoom bug.
 Script by @scottjehl, rebound by @wilto.
 MIT / GPLv2 License.
*/
(function(w){

    // This fix addresses an iOS bug, so return early if the UA claims it's something else.
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if( !( /iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test( navigator.platform ) && /OS [1-5]_[0-9_]* like Mac OS X/i.test(ua) && ua.indexOf( "AppleWebKit" ) > -1 ) ){
        return;
    }

    var doc = w.document;

    if( !doc.querySelector ){ return; }

    var meta = doc.querySelector( "meta[name=viewport]" ),
        initialContent = meta && meta.getAttribute( "content" ),
        disabledZoom = initialContent + ",maximum-scale=1",
        enabledZoom = initialContent + ",maximum-scale=10",
        enabled = true,
        x, y, z, aig;

    if( !meta ){ return; }

    function restoreZoom(){
        meta.setAttribute( "content", enabledZoom );
        enabled = true;
    }

    function disableZoom(){
        meta.setAttribute( "content", disabledZoom );
        enabled = false;
    }

    function checkTilt( e ){
        aig = e.accelerationIncludingGravity;
        x = Math.abs( aig.x );
        y = Math.abs( aig.y );
        z = Math.abs( aig.z );

        // If portrait orientation and in one of the danger zones
        if( (!w.orientation || w.orientation === 180) && ( x > 7 || ( ( z > 6 && y < 8 || z < 8 && y > 6 ) && x > 5 ) ) ){
            if( enabled ){
                disableZoom();
            }           
        }
        else if( !enabled ){
            restoreZoom();
        }
    }

    w.addEventListener( "orientationchange", restoreZoom, false );
    w.addEventListener( "devicemotion", checkTilt, false );

})( this );
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in iOS 4 which can be remedied with the following Javascript snippet, however it disables the user's ability to do pinch-to-zoom:

https://gist.github.com/901295/229d163414e22ebb14a6a6ba0b9777118f02e52d

Answer (score 1):

**This one works !**

```
 <script >
// BUG orientation portrait/lanscape IOS //
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
if (viewportmeta) {
    viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0';
    document.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1';
    }, false);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for the script to work and bypass the 2nd gesture minor tweaking like in orienatation change event set the max to 1.00099 instead of just 1.0

Answer (score 0):

When you say it scales the page up, is that all elements, or just the text font size?... For fixing the font size you can use:

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It scales up all the elements, it basically just zooms into the page.

Comment: I revised it to use 100% rather than none, which stops the text size from changing on orientation change, but still allows the user to zoom. What other types of elements are you having trouble with? I'm assuming some elements, like a banner you'd want some fluidity in the width, but control the height with CSS.

Comment: I have tried using 100% for webkit-text-size-adjust, but it doesn't stop the webpage from scaling incorrectly when the iPad is rotated.

Comment: I have the same problem (and it's not the text-size-adjust though that is important to set too), fluid sites seem to have this problem on iPads going from portrait to landscape with enabled zooming, same question here: [How do I reset the scale/zoom of a web app on an orientation change on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphone) but no solution there yet that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a different solution to keep the zoom at 1 on rotation, but allow the user to pinch-to-zoom. Basically when the user zooms, javascript changes the viewport zoom level (and the native browser zoom functionality is disabled).

See it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878932/436776

Answer (score 0):

The first fix worked for me with the following changes.

Change initial scale to .8, minimum to .25 and maximum to 1.6.

Use the "meta" tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<script ="text/javascript">
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
    if (viewportmeta) {
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=.25, maximum-scale=1.6, initial-scale=.8';
        document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () {
            viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6';
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to meta:

```
%meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6, user-scalable=yes", name: "viewport"}
```

to global script:

```
if navigator.platform.toLowerCase() is "ipad"
  viewport = $ "meta[name='viewport']"
  viewport_content = viewport.attr("content")

  # reset initial zoom
  viewport.attr "content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"
  setTimeout =>
    viewport.attr "content", viewport_content
  , 0

  # reset zoom on rotate
  timeout = null
  window.onorientationchange = ->
    clearTimeout timeout if timeout?
    viewport.attr "content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"
    timeout = setTimeout =>
      viewport.attr "content", viewport_content
    , 1000
```