# How do I make iPads not zoom my web page when they rotate?

Tags: ios, ipad, zooming

I have a web page that works no matter what size the viewport is, so it shows up well on iPad in either landscape or portrait mode.  However, when you rotate from landscape to portrait, the iPad zooms in, and when you rotate back it doesn't zoom back out again.

Is there a way to make it zoom back out?  Or not zoom in in the first place?  The app should be fullscreen most of the time, after all.

I've tried playing with meta viewport, but disabling user scaling just means once it automatically zooms in you're stuck and you can't zoom back out again.

Comment: did you try setting the scalesPageToFit property of webView to NO?

Comment: This is in a browser, not an iOS application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad layout scales up when rotating from portrait to landcape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434656/ipad-layout-scales-up-when-rotating-from-portrait-to-landcape)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have disabled user zooming and have used a media query to tell users to keep their device landscape for the best experience (it's a web based presentation) but if they have the device portrait at all it messes up the scaling when it switches back to landscape and they can't get back to the original state.

**Update:**

Worked out a fix for this issue. You need to make sure that the viewport meta has maximum and minimum scales set to 1 as well. Eg:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Yeah.  Setting min/max scale seems to be the only way.  Fortunately you can set and unset it quickly to get the same effect, without disabling zooming.