# How do you change zoom level dynamically with Javascript?

Tags: jquery, viewport, pinchzoom

I'm trying to figure out how to reset the zoom level in a webpage for ios. It seems that when the user does a pinch zoom in/out the zoom feature no longer works. I want pinch gestures, but want to programatically reset the zoom. Anyone have ideas on changing zoom dynamically with Javascript/jQuery?

```
<meta id="viewportMeta" name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5" />


$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#zoomOut").click(function(){
            $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'initial-scale=0.5; maximum-scale1; user-scalable=1;');
        });

      $("#zoomIn").click(function(){
             $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;');
        });
});
```

Comment: Could you state if your code is not doing what is intended? Or are you seeking additional ideas on how else you can do this?

Answer (score 16):

------ Update ------

This is not an issue anymore in iOS7. And there is better fix by Scott Jehl on github [scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix](https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix) that works for iOS6.

------ Original answer ------

Taking answers from these:

- [iPad layout scales up when rotating from portrait to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434656/ipad-layout-scales-up-when-rotating-from-portrait-to-landscape)
- [How do I reset the scale/zoom of a web app on an orientation change on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557801/how-do-i-reset-the-scale-zoom-of-a-web-app-on-an-orientation-change-on-the-iphon)

---

Jeremy Keith ([@adactio](http://twitter.com/adactio)) has a good solution for this on his blog [Orientation and scale](http://adactio.com/journal/4470/)

Keep the Markup scalable by not setting a maximum-scale in markup.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Then disable scalability with javascript on load until gesturestart when you allow scalability again with this script:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
    if (viewportmeta) {
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0';
        document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () {
            viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6';
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you pinch zoom, why doesn't it allow it to reset the initial-scale?

Comment: This question is old, but i just upvoted your answer because its correct, and extremely annoying when the asker of the question cannot take the time out of their day to thank you by choosing yours as correct.

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm. Placed code in a file and added to head.

Comment: Updating the viewport meta with JS did no trigger a change of scaling in my tests on mobile safari ios7.

Comment: @coulix it works differently now is iOS7. I've updated my answer to make this more relevant.

Comment: This code will prevent zooming from happening in the first place, but if the browser is already zoomed in, is there a way to dynamically de-zoom?