# Force Ipad to zoom out when changed from landscape to portrait

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ipad, scale

I have created a responsive site that looks good down to 1000px and screens smaller than that are redirected to separate mobile site. I intentionally want ipads to view the main site. When you load the site on the Ipad in landscape mode it is perfect but when turned it it too zoomed in. It there a way using meta tags and scale to force scale to say .75 when turned?

I have tried looking around and can make the site load zoomed out if first loaded in portrait but have not been able to force it zoom out on the turn.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give this link a shot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379407/1011998 Essentially, with a bit of HTML meta tags and a snippet of JavaScript, you should be well on your way to elegant scaling.