# Website renders normally in iOS6, but double size in iOS5 iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, media-queries

I could not google out that Safari on iOS5 renders websites in **double size** comparable to Safari on iOS6. However, this is exactly what I can see using my **iOS Simulator**.

I have MacOS 10.7. I am currently testing iPad2, however it seems I have the same problems on iPhone4.

- Has anyone met such problems?
- How can I prevent this?
- Can I detect iOS5 vs iOS6 using media queries?

I am putting all my CSS code here, however it is tooooo big and this can not contain the answer:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* -- Main CSS -- */

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

body.IE {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
}

body.notIE {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.container {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(238,238,238,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eeeeee',GradientType=0 );
}

.container::before, .container::after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
}

.calendar_holder {
    margin: 2em auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 960px;
}

.calendar {
    height: 640px;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #999, 0 0 1.88em 1.88em #CCC;
}

.calendar h1 {
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-top-left-radius: inherit;
    border-top-right-radius: inherit;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-size: 2.75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}

.calendar p {
    padding: 1em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.calendar p.winner {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.calendar p.winner strong {
    color: #2C86C2;
}

.day {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.25)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1affffff', endColorstr='#40ffffff',GradientType=1 );
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5), 0 0 1px 1px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.25) inset;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0.188em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), -1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0.188em;
    position: relative; /* to keep transforms working */
    overflow: hidden;   /* to keep transforms working */
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

.day time {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.25)), color-stop(20%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0.25) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 20%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#40ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 );
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    position: relative;
}


.day_holder .day time .date_day {
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}

.day_holder .day time .date_month {
    font-size: 90%;
}


.day_holder {
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-filter: sepia(25%);
    background: none!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

.day_holder .day:hover {
    background: none;
}

.day_holder .day div {
    -webkit-transition: bottom 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: bottom 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: bottom 0.25s ease-in-out;
    content: 'Click to win!';
    font-size: 0.65em;
    line-height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    bottom: -2.7em;
}

.day_holder:hover .day div {
    bottom: 0;
}

.question_pane {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    top: 6.35em;
    max-height: 86%;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 5%;
    min-height: 40%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.prize_pane,.sponsor_pane {
    position: absolute;
    right: 6.05%;
    width: 43.95%;
}

.prize_pane {
    max-height: 57.75%;
    top: 5.625em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}

.sponsor_pane {
    bottom: 2em;
}

.sponsor_pane h2 {
    display: none;
}

.calendar h2 {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    font-size: 1.15em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.prize_pane img {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}

.sponsor_pane img {

}

.calendar img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

form {
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

fieldset legend, fieldset strong {
    line-height: 2em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

form ul, form ol {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

form li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

form ol {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin: 0;
}

form ol li {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    color: #FF6838;
}

form ul.answers {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    max-height: 4.5em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

form ul.answers li {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    min-height: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

form input[type="radio"] {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0.05em 1em;
}

form label {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), -1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
}

form ul.answers label {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.094px;
}

form input {
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 75%;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 1em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 0.1em 0.75em;
}

form input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

form input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0.6em 1em;
}

form input[type="submit"],.btn-success {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000',GradientType=0 );
    background-color: #71C502;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
}

form input[type="submit"]:hover, .btn-success:hover {
    background-color: #84BB49;
}

.btn-success {
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}

form hr {
    margin: 1em 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    height: 1px;
}

.backlink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5em;
    left: -1.4em;
}

.backlink a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    text-indent: -0.1em;
}

.backlink a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}


/* ----------------- ALL MOBILE ----------------------- */

@media (max-width : 1025px) {

    .container, .calendar_holder, .calendar {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container {
        background: rgb(253,255,255);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(253,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(196,196,196,1) 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(253,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(196,196,196,1)));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(253,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(196,196,196,1) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(253,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(196,196,196,1) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(253,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(196,196,196,1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(253,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(196,196,196,1) 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fdffff', endColorstr='#c4c4c4',GradientType=0 );
    }

    .calendar_holder {
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .calendar {
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        background-size: cover!important;
        background-attachment: fixed!important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
        background-position: center center!important;
    }

    .calendar h1 {
        font-size: 1.25em;
        margin: 0;
    }

    form .rememberMe {
        width: 80%;
    }

    .prize_pane {
        max-height: none;
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .prize_pane img {
        border: 0;
    }

    .question_pane, .prize_pane, .sponsor_pane {
        position: static;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 1em 5%;
    }
    .backlink {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0.5em;
        bottom: 1em;
    }

    .day_holder {
        width: 4em!important;
        height: 4em!important;
    }

    .day_holder {
        -webkit-filter: none;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        top: auto!important;
        left: auto!important;
        margin: 0.721em;
        background-image: none!important;
    }

    .day {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }

    .day_holder .day time .date_day {
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }

    .day_holder .day time .date_month {
        font-size: 0.65em;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }
    .day_holder .day div {
        display: none;
    }

    .clearfix {
        height: 2em;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .calendar form ul.answers {
        max-height: none;
        overflow-x: visible;
    }

    .calendar form input[type="radio"] {
        width: 5%;
        margin: 0.5em 2% 0.5em 0;
    }

    .calendar form ul.answers label {
        width: 90%;
    }
}


/* These lines are used for scaling */

/* iPad Retina ----------- */
@media (device-height : 2048px) and (device-width : 1536px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}

/* iPad Retina ----------- */
@media (device-height : 2048px) and (device-width : 1536px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation : landscape) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}

/* iPad ----------- */
@media (device-height : 1024px) and (device-width : 768px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 174%;
    }
}

/* iPad ----------- */
@media (device-height : 1024px) and (device-width : 768px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 167%;
    }
}

/* iPhone 5 on iOS5 ----------- */
@media (device-height : 1136px) and (device-width : 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 91%;
    }
}

/* iPhone 5 on iOS5 ----------- */
@media (device-height : 1136px) and (device-width : 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 37%;
        width: 340px;
    }
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media (device-height : 960px) and (device-width : 640px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 74%;
    }
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media (device-height : 960px) and (device-width : 640px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 147.2%;
    }
}

/* iPhone 1-3 ----------- */
@media (device-height : 480px) and (device-width : 320px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 74%;
    }
}

/* iPhone 1-3 ----------- */
@media (device-height : 480px) and (device-width : 320px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 108%;
    }
}

/* iPod ----------- */
@media (device-height : 320px) and (device-width : 240px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 51%;
    }
}

/* iPod ----------- */
@media (device-height : 320px) and (device-width : 240px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 62%;
    }
}

/* hi-res smartphone (Galaxy S3) -----------  todo  BECAUSE WE DONT SUPPORT G3, I COMMENT THIS OUT
@media (min-device-width : 40em) and (device-width : 72em) and (orientation : landscape) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}

@media (min-device-width : 40em) and (device-width : 72em) and (orientation : portrait) {
    .calendar {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we possibly help you without seeing your problem code.

Comment: More specifically show us your viewport meta code.

Comment: Friends, I have rewritten my question

Comment: This did not help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400698/webkit-text-size-adjust-none-doesnt-seem-to-be-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a meta tag issue.

Try this, it works for me across the majority of devices:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```