# text resize none how to apply inline

Tags: iphone, web-applications

i found out the right answer (not to adjust text size on rotation !)
[Preserve HTML font-size when iPhone orientation changes from portrait to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710764/preserve-html-font-size-when-iphone-orientation-changes-from-portrait-to-landscap)

but being very naive to css how to use it inline ?

i used as follows, but it did not work

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style ="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
<font face="Arial" size="9";>< a href="mailto:subject= mysub&attachment=myatt.doc"> mail this< /a>< br/>< b>< i>Header< /i>< /b>< br/></ font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please give some time to format your code properly .... Btw: Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: thanks, i could not find code tag in a hgurry, btw, you know the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The example you point to is a style on the html tag, not the body tag as you have done.  I suggest you try:

```
<html style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
```

and see how that works.  Or you can just put the style into your head section like so:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Prevent font scaling in landscape */
}
</style>
</head>
```

Interesting trick, I haven't actually ever done this myself.

Comment: thanks, none of these worked ! my webview is on a view, could it be a webiew problem ?

Comment: That is a possibility!  Have you tried simply setting the font size you want in pixels?  I don't think it will change on rotation if you do that.

Comment: interesting, font size here does not have any effect !

Comment: Like this: <body style='font-size:14px;'> and then the rest like you have it?